# getting session names from any website?

Tags: php, session-variables

Is it possible to find out if any website is declaring $_SESSION?

If so, get a list of $_SESSION name?

Comment: That would have been a pretty big security risk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by "session name" you mean "the name of a cookie used to hold the token that associates a session with a browser" then make an HTTP request to the site, see if you get a cookie back, apply some heuristics to guess if it is a session token or some other piece of data.

Flaws:

- You will be guessing
- The site might not start a session for every request

If you mean "The pieces of data that are stored in the session", then that is impossible. The data is kept entirely on the server and only the session id token is given to the client — that is the point of sessions.

Answer (score 3):

Nope. It is not possible......